# Different output for printenv and System.getEnv()

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I set a new environment variables in bashrc file. 
Then I restarted the system and printed all the environmental variables using terminal (`printenv`) and eclipse (`System.getEnv()`). The new variable is in the `printenv` result list. But it is not in the `System.getEnv()` result map. 
What is the reason for this?

- OS : Ubuntu 12.10
- IDE : eclipse kepler

Comment: Is the new variable being exported from the shell? Are you starting the JVM from that shell?

Comment: No. How can I do it? And must I do it manually? I thought all environment variables are automatically imported after a restart.

Comment: You have to specifically say `export ENV_VAR`, or they're not passed on to child processes. Look in the stock `rc`/`profile` files (such as `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/profile`) for examples; `PATH` is a very common one.

Comment: I'm not clear on this. I have export it as export TEST_NAME=namalFernando in the .bashrc. Is there any other thing to do than this?

Comment: No, that should be it, but keep in mind that environment variables are inherited by processes. Setting the variable in one shell won't set it in other process trees. In particular, setting an environment variable in `~/.bashrc` won't make it available to your desktop environment and programs launched directly from it (instead of from a shell); you need to configure your DE to add new environment variables if you want them global.

Comment: Got it! Is that mean we cannot set environment variable using .bashrc to pick up in the Eclipse?

Comment: Not if you start Eclipse from the graphical shell. I usually start it from a terminal window, and the `bash` instance there has the variable set. [This article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) may be of help.

Comment: Thank you very much chrylis. When I run it through the terminal it worked correctly. Just one additional question. What is the difference between running eclipse by double clicking the icon and running it through the terminal?

Comment: The difference is the process tree. Environment variables are inherited from parents, and when you run Eclipse from the desktop, it inherits the environment from the GUI (which hasn't set those variables); when you run it from a terminal, the shell has set them, and so Eclipse sees them. If this is an Eclipse-specific setting, consider setting it in your `eclipse.ini` file.